What is the difference between the words "Haus" and "Hause"?
I have seen these words used interchangeably. They are both singular nouns meaning "a house". Are there any contextual differences in their usage?

Related question.

Hause is an older dative singular form. Many nouns allow that extra -e in dative singular. Nowadays you can find it mostly in fixed phrases as im Hause.

Oberrat Huber ist gerade nicht im Hause, sondern zu Tisch.


zu Tisch(e) — having lunch

You could also say zu Tische, the distribution of those extra -e's among the dative forms is a bit random. It all sounds old fashioned.
A huge exception are zu Hause and the alternative zuhause for which the -e form is much more common than the one without -e.
